# Rotate svg pattern around it's center when using objectBoundingBox

Tags: javascript, svg, rotatetransform, wheelnav.js

I need to rotate pattern used as background for svg element (part of wheelnav.js menu) around it's center. I know I can use `patternTransform = rotate(angle, centerX, centerY)`, but the pattern uses `objectBoundingBox` as `patternUnits` and I don't know how to get width and height of the element.

Is there any way to get its dimensions? Or rotate around center without knowing width and height?

**Edit:**

Here is the code I use:

```
var bounRect = document.getElementById("wheelnav-piemenu" + 3 + "-slice-" + 0).getBoundingClientRect()
var patt = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'pattern');
patt.setAttribute('id', 'img' + itemId);
patt.setAttribute('patternUnits', 'objectBoundingBox');
patt.setAttribute('width', '1');
patt.setAttribute('height', '1');
patt.setAttribute('x', '0');
patt.setAttribute('y', '0');
patt.setAttribute('patternTransform',"rotate(" + itemId*-36 + ", 0.5, 0.5)")

var image = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'assets/images/Logo-cropper.png');
image.setAttribute('width', bounRect.width*1.12);
image.setAttribute('height', bounRect.height*1.12);
image.setAttribute('x', -bounRect.height*0.06);
image.setAttribute('y', -bounRect.height*0.04);

var defs = document.getElementsByTagName('defs')[0];
patt.appendChild(image);
defs.appendChild(patt);
```

However it doesn't rotate around its center.

Comment: The width and height of something in objectBoundingBox units is 1 so the centre is (0.5, 0.5)

Comment: I know, but using `rotate(180, 0.5, 0.5)` isn't working (or maybe I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Comment: It's not complete, how do we run your example?

Comment: @RobertLongson to run example you need to add `wheelnav.js` to your site and replace `"wheelnav-piemenu" + 3 + "-slice-" + 0` with id of one of elements of the menu. I thought it was obvious so I didn't write it.